# How to create animation of text where text forms from outline of letters in android?

Tags: android, animation

Animation example link:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M5UBylFj0_8mtOEQT7jjsPN9DcCjyfPI

I want to show my app name in the splash activity with such animation. Can anyone please tell me how to do this? Is there any library on github that I can use for making such animations? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the negative vote?

Comment: Do not include unnecessary tags to question . If you need a library that does not mean you have to add github tag . Its for GIT Versioning not for library .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this myself with an SVG: [See my Codepen](https://codepen.io/YilmazTut/pen/JzaQEy) here. It was an animated logo for a website. If you reload it it draws itself and animates into its place.

You basically animate different paths with css or javascript.
I personally used css by using `animation:` on your path and making a `keyframe` for it that animates it.

Here are some tutorials that helped me out:

- [Animating SVG with CSS](https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/22-animating-svg-css/)
- [Forcing shapes to be paths](https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/26-forcing-shapes-paths/)

**What you are for sure looking for right now:**

- [How SVG Line Drawing Works](https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/28-svg-line-drawing-works/)

The tutorials are great and he has a whole series on that page as you can see.

I hope this was helpfull!

Comment: He also has made a tutorial with javascript if you prefer that.

Comment: Hi. Can you please tell me how can I use this with android?

Comment: im not too familiar with what you mean on android. What exactly do you use to make the app you are working on. because the animation i made is purely html + css. There is a way that you can also animate with code and then use that code to turn the svg into an image and then add it. But it depends on what you have to work with right now.. Would you need code or do you need to upload an image or something

Comment: I am making an android application using java and xml. I need to show the name of my app (which is a String) like this animation.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/27-animating-svg-javascript/ maybe his javascript tutorial then?